# The required anti-forgery form field quot;__RequestVerificationToken is not present

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I have    `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in view and  `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` in controll, but still the error is there. Iam trying to access controller through Ajax. my current code as follows:

**view:**

```
@model learn.ViewModel.tblCategoryVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ganacsi";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_sellerLayout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <!-- navbar vertical -->
        @{ Html.RenderAction("_navbarDashboard", "Home"); }


        <!-- main -->
        <main class="main-content-wrapper">
            <!-- container -->
            <div class="container">
                <!-- row -->
                <div class="row mb-8">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="d-md-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <!-- page header -->
                            <div>
                                <h2>Add New Category</h2>
                                <!-- breacrumb -->
                                <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                                    <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0">
                                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#" class="text-inherit">Dashboard</a></li>
                                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#" class="text-inherit">Categories</a></li>
                                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Add New Category</li>
                                    </ol>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="/dashboard/categories" class="btn btn-light">Back to Categories</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-12">
                        <!-- card -->
                        <div class="card mb-6 shadow border-0">
                            <!-- card body -->
                            <div class="card-body p-6 ">
                                @*<h4 class="mb-5 h5">Category Image</h4>*@
                                @*<div class="mb-4 d-flex">
                                        <div class="position-relative">
                                            <img class="image  icon-shape icon-xxxl bg-light rounded-4" src="../assets/images/icons/bakery.svg" alt="Image">

                                            <div class="file-upload position-absolute end-0 top-0 mt-n2 me-n1">
                                                <input type="file" class="file-input ">
                                                <span class="icon-shape icon-sm rounded-circle bg-white">
                                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil-fill text-muted" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                        <path d="M12.854.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.707 0L10.5 1.793 14.207 5.5l1.647-1.646a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3zm.646 6.061L9.793 2.5 3.293 9H3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.207l6.5-6.5zm-7.468 7.468A.5.5 0 0 1 6 13.5V13h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V12h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V11h-.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V10h-.5a.499.499 0 0 1-.175-.032l-.179.178a.5.5 0 0 0-.11.168l-2 5a.5.5 0 0 0 .65.65l5-2a.5.5 0 0 0 .168-.11l.178-.178z" />
                                                    </svg>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>*@


                                <h4 class="mb-4 h5 mt-5">Category Information</h4>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <!-- input -->
                                    <div class="mb-3 col-lg-6">
                                        <label class="form-label">Category Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Category Name" required id="categoryName">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mb-3 col-lg-6">
                                        <label class="form-label">Publish</label>
                                        <select class="form-select" id="publishDropdown">
                                            @foreach (var status in Model.statusList)
                                            {
                                                <option value="@status">@status</option>
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- input -->
                                    @*<div class="mb-3 col-lg-6">
                                            <label class="form-label">Slug</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Slug" required>
                                        </div>*@
                                    <!-- input -->
                                    @*<div class="mb-3 col-lg-6">
                                            <label class="form-label">Parent Category</label>
                                            <select class="form-select">
                                                <option selected>Category Name</option>
                                                <option value="Dairy, Bread & Eggs">Dairy, Bread & Eggs</option>
                                                <option value="Snacks & Munchies">Snacks & Munchies</option>
                                                <option value="Fruits & Vegetables">Fruits & Vegetables</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-3 col-lg-6">
                                            <label class="form-label">Date</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control flatpickr" placeholder="Select Date">
                                        </div>*@

                                    <div>

                                    </div>
                                    <!-- input -->
                                    <div class="mb-3 col-lg-12 ">
                                        <label class="form-label">Descriptions</label>

                                        <div class="py-8" id="editor"></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- input -->
                                    <div class="mb-3 col-lg-12 ">
                                        <label class="form-label" id="productSKU">Active/Disable</label><br>
                                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="activeRadioOptions"
                                                   id="inlineRadio1" value="Y" checked>
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Active</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- input -->
                                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="activeRadioOptions"
                                                   id="inlineRadio2" value="N">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Disabled</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- input -->

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-3 col-lg-12 mt-5">
                                        <h4 class="mb-4 h5">Meta Data</h4>

                                        <!-- input -->
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label class="form-label">Meta Title</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" id="metaTitle">
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- input with dynamic keyword display -->
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label class="form-label">Meta Description</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="metaKeyword" placeholder="Meta Description"></textarea>
                                        </div>

                                        <div id="keywordBox" class="keyword-box"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveCategoryBtn">
                                            Create Product
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary ms-2">
                                            Save
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="d-grid">
                                        <small class="form-text clsErrorMsg" id="ErrMsg" style=" text-align: center; color:red;"></small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </main>

    </div>

}



<script src="../assets/js/vendors/editor.js"></script>

<script>
    const metaKeyword = document.getElementById('metaKeyword');
    const keywordBox = document.getElementById('keywordBox');

    metaKeyword.addEventListener('input', updateKeywordBox);

    function updateKeywordBox() {
        const keywordsArray = metaKeyword.value.split(/\s*,\s*/);
        const keywordBoxContent = keywordsArray.map(keyword => `<span class="keyword-tag">${keyword.trim()} <span class="close-icon" onclick="removeKeyword(this)">&times;</span></span>`).join(' ');
        keywordBox.innerHTML = keywordBoxContent;
    }

    function removeKeyword(element) {
        const keyword = element.previousSibling.textContent.trim();
        const keywordsArray = metaKeyword.value.split(/\s*,\s*/).filter(kw => kw !== keyword);
        metaKeyword.value = keywordsArray.join(', ');
        updateKeywordBox();
    }
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#saveCategoryBtn').click(function () {
            showLoader();

            var csrfToken = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
            console.log('CSRF Token:', csrfToken);
            var categoryName = $('#categoryName').val();
            var published = $('#publishDropdown').val();

            var description = htmlEncode(document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML);
            var status = $('input[name="activeRadioOptions"]:checked').val();
            var metaTitle = $('#metaTitle').val();
            var metaKeyword = $('#metaKeyword').val();

            //   var files = Array.from($('#uploadImage')[0].files);


            if (!categoryName) {
                displayError("Enter category Name ....");
                return;
            }
            else if (!publishDropdown) {
                displayError("Select Publish Type ....");
                return;
            } else if (!description) {
                displayError("Enter Product description ....");
                return;
            } else if (!status) {
                displayError("Select status ....");
                return;
            } else if (!metaTitle) {
                displayError("Enter Meta Title ....");
                return;
            } else if (!metaKeyword) {
                displayError("Enter Meta Keyword ....");
                return;
            }

            else {
                displayError("");
                hideLoader();
            }

            var formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('categoryName', categoryName);
            formData.append('description', description);
            formData.append('published', published);
            formData.append('metaTitle', metaTitle);
            formData.append('metaKeyword', metaKeyword);
            formData.append('status', status);

            //for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            //    formData.append('files', files[i]);
            //    console.log(files[i]);
            //}

            //var imagePaths = files.map(file => '~/assets/images/products/' + file.name).join(',');

            //formData.append('imagePaths', imagePaths);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/dashboard/AddSellerCategory',
                type: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'RequestVerificationToken': csrfToken
                },
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data === true) {
                        alert('Category saved successfully.');
                        location.href = 'dashboard/categories';
                    }

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert('Error saving the Category.');
                },
                complete: function () {
                    hideLoader();
                }
            });
        });

        function displayError(errorMessage) {
            $("#ErrMsg").css("display", "inline-block");
            $("#ErrMsg").text(errorMessage);
            hideLoader();
        }

        function htmlEncode(str) {
            return String(str)
                .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
                .replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
        }

    });

</script>
```

**controller:**

```
#region Add Category
        public ActionResult add_category()
        {
            tblCategoryVM category = new tblCategoryVM();
            category.statusList = BindCategoryType();
            return View(category);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public JsonResult AddSellerCategory(categoryVM category)
        {
            try
            {
                using (LearnDBEntities context = new LearnDBEntities())
                {
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
                    SqlDataReader sqlReader;
                    try
                    {
                        AntiForgery.Validate();

                        string strSQL = "Addtblcategory";

                        //List<string> imagePaths = new List<string>();
                        string ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
                        SqlCommand AccountCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
                        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                            con.Open();

                        AccountCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        AccountCommand.CommandText = strSQL;

                        AccountCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Category", category.categoryName));
                        AccountCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Published", category.published));
                        AccountCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", category.description));
                        AccountCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MetaTitle", category.metaTitle));
                        AccountCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MetaKeyword", category.metaKeyword));
                        AccountCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Show", category.status));
                        AccountCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CreatedOn", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                        AccountCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@createdBy", Session["CartUser"].ToString()));

                        sqlReader = AccountCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string message = ex.Message;
                        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Error saving the product: " + ex.Message;
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class categoryVM
    {
        public string categoryName { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string published { get; set; }
        public string metaTitle { get; set; }
        public string metaKeyword { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
```

Iam getting token value in console.log.